# How to display a graphite graph of used memory when you have total memory and free memory

Tags: graphite, metrics

My servers send `mem_total` and `mem_free` metrics to Graphite, but I'd like to display `mem_used` on my dashboard. I'm currently solving the problem by doing:

```
offset(scale(servers.foo.*.mem_free,-1),30823052)
```

where `30823052`k is the total memory.

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can leverage graphite to calculate `mem_used` from `mem_total` and `mem_free` for me, so that I can avoid having to hard-code the amount of total memory in my query?

I have been doing some testing with Grafana lately, and have figured out a partial solution, which is:

```
A) servers.foo.server1.mem_total (mark invisible)
B) servers.foo.server1.mem_free (mark invisible)
C) diffSeries(#A, #B)
```

but, this solution only works without wildcards - and I really really want to be able to use wildcards rather than having to do this kind of thing for every single server.

I was looking at the available functions, and groupByNode seems like it might be a part of the solution I'm looking for, but I haven't figured out a way to do what I want with it yet.

Comment: KarlHungus on freenode in #graphite pointed out that the latest version of graphite supports Map/Reduce functions: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.reduceSeries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using [`mapSeries`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.mapSeries) and [`reduceSeries`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.reduceSeries).

```
reduceSeries(mapSeries(servers.foo.*.*,2),"diffSeries",3,"mem_total","mem_free")
```